# How to pass data from Fragment to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm newbie in Android dev, and I'm getting a problem.
I've created a Fragment for my app.
This Fragment call a Asynctask to get data from my Database.

BUT when I want to pass these datas from my Fragment to my mainActivity, I'm getting a crash. Here is what my void looks like :

`

```
    public void returnedFromConnexionAsynctask(String returned) {
         Log.i(LOG_TAG, returned);
         if(mActivity!=null){
((MainActivity) getActivity()).returnedFromConnexionFragment(returned);
          }
          else {
              Log.i(LOG_TAG,"getActivity is null");
          }
    }
```

`

mActivity looks like this:

```
public Context mActivity;

@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mActivity = context;
    }
```

I've tried a lot of things, but I dont know what to do...
Thanks !

Comment: Please specify the nature of the crash. You say you have tried a lot of things - list them.

Comment: Please show the exception message

Comment: I'm getting "getActivity is null" in my Log. Should I use the onAttach method ?

Comment: Yea use it in any method coming after on attach and before on detach/destroy view/destroy

Comment: `This Fragment call a Asynctask to get data from my Database.` your problem is more fundamental, you should use Room's `LiveData<List<T>>` to observe the database query and have it be evaluated on background thread by Room itself automatically

Answer (score 0):

You have to use callback interface that your activity will implement. Andoird studio generates such stub for you when creating new fragment from wizard. Try it out.

When you will have such interface, during `onAttach` you are saving reference to activity in fragment and voila

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily the best way to do this (using an interface as described here is probably the best way [Communicating with activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)).

You could create setter methods in your activity for class members. Then in your fragment, you can do this:

```
((mActivity)getActivity()).setContext(context);
```

Again, this isn't the best way, but probably the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an interface and declare a callback method say

```
public interface xyz{
    public void callback( yourdata here );
}
```

Implement this interface in your activity and implement the method to do what you want with the returned info.

Now inside your fragment do this:

```
((xyz)getActivity()).callback(put your data here);
```

Comment: Okay, so I've made my Callback in my mainActivity, but still getting the error "getActivity is null" in my log. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Where are you calling this? I would suggest you do this in onCreateView... I'm guessing you're doing it early in the life cycle of the fragment where it's still not attached to the activity

Comment: Yea you can use it, but i guess put nullity and !isFinished and !isDestroyed checks before using it. Since fragments are attached to activity life cycle events, the context will not leak